# Injecting CSS into Selenium driver causes javascript error in Linux, not in macOS

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver-python, selenium-webdriver4

Below python (v. 3.9.7) function is injecting CSS styles, that are loaded from a standard CSS file, into a selenium driver object. While in macOS (11.5.2, homebrew) the styles are applied correctly, in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) the styles were not applied and this message is thrown out: `javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token`

So which part of the string is causing the issue and how do I have to preprocess the string before sending it?

```
def injectCSS(driver, file):
    css = Path(file).read_text()
    css = css.replace('\n', '')
    execute = rf'''
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = '{css}';
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    '''
    try:
        driver.execute_script(execute)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('CSS injection done')
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

**UPDATE:** I narrowed down the problematic string: it's not the string in the Python variable, it's located inside the loaded CSS file itself and it's the line containing the `src` attribute in a `@font-face` rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "myfont";
    src: url(http://my.font.com/font.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** Well, thanks to @cruisepandey I figured out the problematic markup in the CSS: it's the single quotes inside the CSS file, e.g. `font-family: 'serif';`. Replacing them with double quotes fixes the problem.
Why single quotationmarks in the variable are allowed, but not in the CSS file itself? Also: why does the issue occur in linux and not in macOS?

Comment: Are you getting exception at this line `style.type = 'text/css';` ?

Comment: In terminal, no line number is mentioned. There's just a stacktrace in this form: #0 0x55b262372d93 <unknown> …

Comment: Deleting the line `style.type = 'text/css';` doesn't make the warning disappear.

Comment: I narrowed down the problematic string inside the CSS file and updated my question accordingly.